# Why GEE calculates the area differently?

Tags: google-earth-engine

https://code.earthengine.google.com/4804f3a84fd1e186ba8a1d29bdc19d4a

Here's the code. I try to get the area where NDVI>8. I just wonder why I get two different area calculate results between area1 and area2. I just move the updateMask. Why it caused the change?

```
var img=S2.map(NDVI).first().select("ndvi")
var test=img.updateMask(img.select("ndvi").gt(0.8))
var areamask1 =ee.Image.pixelArea().updateMask(test);
var area1=areamask1.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: dianchi,
    // crs: 'EPSG:32645', // WGS Zone N 45
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1E13
  });
print(area1.get("area"),  'area1')

var areamask2 =ee.Image.pixelArea().updateMask(img.select("ndvi").gt(0.8))
var area2=areamask2.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: dianchi,
    // crs: 'EPSG:32645', // WGS Zone N 45
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1E13
  });
print(area2,"area2");
```

Which way is right to get the area?

And I checked `areamask1` and `areamask2`. The same pixel of `areamask1` and `areamask2` has the same value, so why the recuder of them are different? If I masked them differently, `areamask1` and `areamask2` should also be different.But now they have same value between `areamask1` and `areamask2`? But`areamask1`has a percentage("84%" of this pixel). What does it mean?

[image]

And I thought `areamask2` should be a constant image, isn't it? If the second case I have a binary mask, then why `areamask2` each pixel has different value?

Answer (score 1):

Every image (or more precisely, every band), has a mask value for each pixel, which is a number between 0 and 1. This is *not* the same as an image “being” a mask. So, let's look at exactly what your operations did. In the first case:

- `img.select("ndvi").gt(0.8)` **has the same mask** as `img`, but has its data replaced with either 0 or 1 according to the condition.
- `var test = img.updateMask(img.select("ndvi").gt(0.8))` is taking the *values* from `img` (because that's on the left side) but has a binary (0 or 1) mask such that only the values greater than 0.8 are unmasked.
- `var areamask1 = ee.Image.pixelArea().updateMask(test);` has values which are areas, and **its mask consists of NDVI values from `test`.** This is probably not what you want. This is why you saw an 84% mask in the inspector — that pixel had an NDVI of 0.84.

In the other case of `areamask2`, you have taken the binary image `img.select("ndvi").gt(0.8)` and used it to mask off the area image. This is probably what you wanted.

To modify `areamask1` to get the right answer, you would want to replace

```js
var test = img.updateMask(img.select("ndvi").gt(0.8));
```

with

```js
var test = img.select("ndvi").gt(0.8);
```

so that the image has the *data* that you want to become `areamask`'s mask. The mask doesn't need to be modified.